# Mouse Position without Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have programmed an audio spectrum analyzer in python with pyqtgraph library. I would like to save the cursor position when I click on the spectrum window.

I know it's possible to do that with Tkinter but I didn't create the window with tkinter so I have to find another way to do it.

Comment: [GetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390(v=vs.85).aspx), accessible via ctypes or win32api? (Windows only, obv)

Comment: I removed the `tkinter` tag since you specifically say you want a solution that does _not_ use `tkinter`.